# Email address regular expression, limited character before and after @ symbol

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, validation

I have a regexp that check for valid email.

`/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;`

how would I limit the number of character before @ to 64 and after @ to 64.

Comment: By not using `+` and `*` but instead ranges, i.e. `{1,}` and `{0,}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. After your long regex test, do a second regex test for length:

   `/^.{1,64}@.{1,64}$)$/`
2. Prefix a positive lookahead to your regex:

   `/(?=^.{1,64}@.{1,64}$)^(YOUR REGEX)$/`

Comment: @AmigoJack: Yup, same result, possibly even a bit faster

Comment: Speed is not the point: you want anything BUT an `@` before finding an `@` - in that case NEVER mindlessly use `.`

Comment: @AmigoJack: You are right if this is the only validation for email address. As described, both of my examples assume charles okojie will use his validation *and* my length check regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple regex example:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{7}$/
```

This expression means:

- A single character between A-Z
- A single character between a-z
- Finally, matches exactly 7 times -> {7}

You can simply add your regex `{64}` to check if it's 64 character long or not.